# Change display orientation with pygame

Tags: pygame, orientation, display

```
import sys
import pygame
import pygame.locals as pgl


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.flags = pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.NOFRAME | pygame.VIDEORESIZE
        self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), self.flags, 0, 0)
        self.width, self.height = self.surface.get_size()
        self.bgcolor = (255, 255, 255)
        print(f'INIT => VIDEO SIZE: {self.width}, {self.height}')

    def __del__(self):
        pygame.display.quit()

    def process_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.handle_event(event)

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pgl.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pgl.K_ESCAPE:
                self.running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
        elif (event.type == pgl.VIDEORESIZE):
            print(f'HANDLE EVENT => VIDEO RESIZE: {event.w}, {event.h}')
            self.width, self.height = self.height, self.width
            #self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), self.flags, 0, 0)
            self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), self.flags, 0, 0)
            self.width, self.height = self.surface.get_size()
            print(f'HANDLE EVENT => NEW SIZE: {self.width}, {self.height}')
            self.orientation_changed()

    def orientation_changed(self):
        # do something here
        pass

    def draw(self):
        r = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.bgcolor, r)
        pygame.display.update()

    def run(self):
        self.running = True

        while self.running:

            self.process_events()
            self.draw()


test = Test()
test.run()
```

Running this code I have:

```
INIT => VIDEO SIZE: 1366, 768
HANDLE EVENT => VIDEO RESIZE: 768, 1332
HANDLE EVENT => NEW SIZE: 1366, 768
HANDLE EVENT => VIDEO RESIZE: 1366, 734
HANDLE EVENT => NEW SIZE: 1366, 768
```

This show the display height with a wrong size.

And the white background do not cover all the screen size when I rotate the device.

Now, when I uncomment the line 31 and comment line 32, I get an error:

```
INIT => VIDEO SIZE: 1366, 768
HANDLE EVENT => VIDEO RESIZE: 768, 1332
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/test/python/test.py", line 56, in <module>
    test.run()
  File "/home/dev/test/python/test.py", line 51, in run
    self.process_events()
  File "/home/dev/test/python/test.py", line 20, in process_events
    self.handle_event(event)
  File "/home/dev/test/python/test.py", line 31, in handle_event
    self.surface = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height), self.flags, 0, 0)
pygame.error: No video mode large enough for 768x1366
```

Someone has an idea why the display is not changing its orientation and why create another with the right size gives an error.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think because pygame already has a window initialized it will not be able to resize the window.

pygame wiki about this: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/WindowResizing

*In Pygame 2
In pygame 2 the display surface is automatically resized when the window is - set_mode() should not be called. The VIDEORESIZE event instead lets us handle any other surfaces, or anything else, we might want to resize.
Example:*

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500), RESIZABLE)
pic = pygame.image.load("example.png")  # You need an example picture in the same folder as this file!
running = True
while running:
    pygame.event.pump()
    event = pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type == QUIT:
        running = False
    elif event.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, event.dict['size']), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
    elif event.type == VIDEOEXPOSE:  # handles window minimising/maximising
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, screen.get_size()), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()
```

So I think the only way of getting around this, is by closing and re-opening the window, or by using a different surface which will not help as well.

Or if I didnt understand your question or my answer is wrong: I think it may be this in your code:

```
self.width, self.height = self.height, self.width
```

I think you want this to be:

```
self.width, self.height = event.w, event.h
```